# Angular web app 13 ngx-barcode-scanner doesn't work on mobile version

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile, camera, barcode-scanner

Hello I have a problem with ngx-barcode-scanner.

I install ngx-barcode-scanner no matter what version of angular (currently 13). After installing and creating a simple desktop application (chrome) everything works fine. Unfortunately, opening a web application on a mobile phone the library does not work properly.
The browser does not even ask for permissions to use the camera.
On this demo it works correctly on my phone and on me it doesn't anymore:
[https://julienboulay.github.io/ngx-barcode-scanner/livestream](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Will someone tell me if it is at all feasible to create a web app with abrcode/qrcode scanning capability using mobile without creating a native app? Maybe I am doing something wrong please help and regards.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { QuaggaJSResultObject } from '@ericblade/quagga2';
import { BarcodeScannerLivestreamComponent } from "ngx-barcode-scanner";

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
@ViewChild(BarcodeScannerLivestreamComponent)
barcodeScanner!: BarcodeScannerLivestreamComponent;
barcodeValue: any
name = 'Angular';
torch = false;
wasFound = true
availableDevices!: MediaDeviceInfo[];
deviceCurrent!: MediaDeviceInfo;

@Input() deviceId!: string;
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.barcodeScanner.start();
}

onValueChanges(result: QuaggaJSResultObject) {
 this.barcodeValue = result.codeResult.code;
 if (result.codeResult.code) {
   this.wasFound = false;
 }
}

}
```

**app.module.html**

````
<barcode-scanner-livestream [deviceId]="deviceId" [type]="['code_128', 'code_39', 'ean_8']"
  [errorFilter]="{ median: 0.08, threshold: 0.1 }" (valueChanges)="onValueChanges($event)"
  [torch]="torch"></barcode-scanner-livestream>
<div [hidden]="!barcodeValue">
  {{ barcodeValue }}
</div>
<video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
</video>```

I would like ngx-barcode-scanner to work for me using the webcam and using the phone's camera.
````

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to create a Progressive web app, which can be added to your homescreen? I had some problems trying to create a PWA and accessing the camera from there. Nevertheless it seems as this restriction is solved since iOS 13.

Comment: I am trying to create a web application that has in it a barcode-scanner that works not only with webcam but also on mobile browser (chrome, safari). Is this at all possible?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible. Currently I have problems identifying the problem exactly since no error is pasted. Maybe you can try to use web inspector plugin to see if any error occurs?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. Simply on the computer scanner works and on the phone it does not. The camera does not display.
I use this package: ngx-barcode-scanner

Comment: Have you granted the website permission to use the camera? Usually there is a popup where you have to accept the usage of the camera for each domain. Maybe you accidentally rejected it?